# FCM and Flutter - MessageID is not the same when sending and receiving notifications when they are received in background

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a problem receiving and storing notifications using FCM and Flutter. It goes like this:

I've set up a Cloud Function that sends a notification to users subscribed to a topic, like this prototype:

```
   const topic = 'all-users';
   const message = {
         notification: {
            title: data.title,
            body: data.body,
            image: data.image_url
         },
         data: {
            urlToLaunch: data.link_url,
            
         },
         apns: {
            payload: {
               aps: {
                  'content-available': true,
               }
            }
         },
         android: {
            notification: {
               
               sound: 'default'
            }
         },
         topic: topic
         
   };
var notificationResponse = await admin.messaging().send(message);

//get the part of string 'messageID' after 'projects/*******/messages/'
var messageID = notificationResponse.substring(notificationResponse.indexOf('projects/****/messages/') + 33);
console.log(messageID);
```

I get the notificationResponse in the form of "projects/{project-name}/messages/{message-id}, and then log the message to firestore. So far so good, everything works fine and I receive the notification in my app.

In my app, I've set up an handler for background notifications, that goes like this

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  
... //handles the message
```

The problem is that, **only when receiving the notification with tha app in terminated state (closed with app switcher)**, I receive a messageId (accessed by message.messageId), that is in a different format, like 0:1684403807391896%ec060715ec060715

So what happens is that the id stored on firestore and the id that I store in the app db is different.

This is a problem, because I need some uniqueID to backup notifications from Firestore, remove duplicates, generate reports and other filtering staff. Why is that happening? What I need, is a reference to the same notification, both server and client-side.

I can't believe that this doesn't exist, but I searched the documentation for FCM and the firebase_messaging library for Flutter and I did not find anything.

Am I missing something? Thank you for your help!